# isActiveMFASession doesn't appear to be returned from SM-MFA

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I am working with the SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMFA starter pack and have discovered an issue. When I register a user I am prompted to setup MFA which works as intended. However, when I try to login with SSO I am being prompted for MFA again.

I have verified that I am not sending prompt=login.

I have attempted to search for an answer with no results or dead ends.

here is code snippets from my trustframeworkbase.xml

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Here is my SM-MFA

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SM-MFA">
          <DisplayName>Session Mananagement Provider</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.DefaultSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isActiveMFASession" DefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Bump. Looking for a MS response.

Comment: Bump Again. Looking for a MS response since this is MS recommended escalation path.

Comment: still searching for a solution - did u finally found how to settle that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I  think you have used "SM-MFA" technical profile inside "PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" technical profile. So till this "PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" technical profile is called, the claim "isActiveMFASession" will not exist and it will trigger MFA every time. Hence, this OrchestrationStep isn't being skipped, because the "isActiveMFASession" claim doesn't exist.

Comment: That is correct, SM-MFA is inside the technical profile "PhoneFactor-inputOrVerify" however the documentation indicates that the orchestration step checks for a SSO provider and populates the claims prior to executing. Either this is a bug, or the documentation needs to be updated.